# Starting worker with dynamic routing_key?

Tags: python, celery

I have one queue with several task types and I need to run worker for specific task.
Something like: 'celery worker --routing_key task.type1 --app=app'

Queue configuration:

```
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('myqueue',    routing_key='task.#'),
)
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'topic'
```

Using pika task is easy to solve: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html but how to do it with celery?

Comment: I am not sure if you can start a worker for a specific key, but you can route that specific task to another queue & start worker for that particular queue.

Comment: Yes I known, but I have requirement to use only one queue.

Comment: If you don't want to run other tasks at all, you can remove autodiscover tasks and specify the only task to celery.

Answer (score 3):

Np, you can't bind a worker to a routing_key.

- Workers consume queues not routing_key.
- Producers send messages with a routing_key, that rabbitmq route to queues.

It's not possible with pika also.

In the tutorial the worker/consumer binds its own queue to the routing key.

1. The producer emit logs with routing key = 'info'
2. RabbitMQ will discard all of them until a queue is bound to this routing_key
3. The receiver create a Queue A and bind it to routing_key 'info'
4. Now rabbitmq routes logs with routing_key 'info' to Queue A, and the receiver consume them

You can reproduce this binding easily with celery.

In exemple you can do it in the celery configuration file:

```
 exchange = Exchange('default', type=topic)
 CELERY_QUEUES = (
   Queue('all_logs', exchange, routing_key='logs.#'),
   Queue('info_logs', exchange, routing_key='logs.info')
  )
```

receive all logs:

```
$ celery worker -A receive_logs -Q all_logs
```

receive only 'info' logs (msg with routing_key=logs.info only)

```
$ celery worker -A receive_logs -Q info_logs
```

In the end you have started a worker that consume only msg with a specific routing_key, which is what you want.

note: info logs are duplicated in both Queue:all_logs  and Queue:info_logs

You might be interested by: 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=direct#std:setting-CELERY_WORKER_DIRECT

Comment: Thanks, for answering, seems like rabbitmq examples with pika confused me.